# Parse : How to custom sort?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I'd like to sort objects by array's index number.

I have a data filled array in a special order and would like show them in that order.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"photoObject"];

[query whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:self.favArray];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
[query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];

    if (!error) {

        self.imageFilesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];
        [self.favCV reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't say which array you're talking about or what the special order is...

Comment: Sorry. As you see there, I'm retrieving objects that match the same objectId as self.favArray's objects. And then, I would like to populate the retrieved objects into self.imageFilesArray by self.favArray's order.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array before setting it to self.imageFilesArray.

Something like that:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(PFObject *a, PFObject *b) {
    return [[a objectForKey:@"index"] compare:[b objectForKey:@"index"]];
}];
self.imageFilesArray = sortedArray;
```

Comment: Hmm no I'm trying to set order from an array in my local database (sqlite). self.favArray is an array filled with data from sqlite and I'd like to sort objects retrieved from Parse in self.favArray's order.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to locally sort as there is no index value to use to sort the data remotely. You should be aware that if you have more results than fit in a page from parse you will need to deal with that...

To sort locally:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    return [@([self.favArray indexOfObject:a]) compare:@([self.favArray indexOfObject:b])];
}];

self.imageFilesArray = sortedArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
    self.imageFilesArray = nil;
    self.imageFilesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.imageFilesArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];

    if (!error) {

        for (PFObject *object in objects) {

            int index = (int)[self.favArray indexOfObject:[object objectId]];
            [self.imageFilesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:object];

        }

        [self.favCV reloadData];
    }
```

And if you need to reverse the order (reversed array's index order)

```
- (void)reverse {
if ([self.imageFilesArray count] <= 1)
    return;
NSUInteger i = 0;
NSUInteger j = [self.imageFilesArray count] - 1;
while (i < j) {
    [self.imageFilesArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i
              withObjectAtIndex:j];

    i++;
    j--;
}}
```

Comment: Is this actually an answer, or an addition to the question?

Comment: This is the answer to my own question which actually works and additionally I'm asking one more question.

Comment: Use an enumerator to reverse the order, much less code. New questions shouldn't be here

Comment: Tried that first but as some claimed it did not work for me. It returned an array with wrong order.